# Как скачать файл с Web-Api по Get запросу на vue js через axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript, rest, axios

Есть API которое по Get запросу позволяет скачать xls файл. У файла уже есть свое имя и его нужно использовать. Задача скачать этот файл, с веб-страницы по кнопке. Так чтобы закачка была в том же окне, при этом на экране у пользователя не должна открываться другая страница. Файл просто должен упасть в закачку, как это обычно бывает. Написал запрос, но не получается, преобразовать ответ в файл.

> код сервера .Net Core Web-Api Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("DownloadExcel")]
    public async Task<FileContentResult> GetExcel()
    {
        var stream = await _service.GetExcel();
        var file = File(
            fileContents: stream.ToArray(),
            contentType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
            fileDownloadName: "остатки.xlsx"
        );
        stream.Close();

        return file;
    }
```

> Код который нужно написать на клиенте

```
downloadExcel() {
    this.isLoading = true
    this.$http.get('/api/restsUpload/DownloadExcel', {

        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        },
    })
        .then((reponse) => {
            // скачать файл
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я делал вот таким образом

```
.then(({ data }) => {
            const link = document.createElement('a');

            link.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);
            link.download = filename;
            link.click();
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил таким образом, хотя хотелось бы покрасивее.

```
downloadExcel() {
    window.open('/api/restsUpload/DownloadExcel')
}
```